# wubi install problem

Tags: installation, wubi, screen

I've been trying to install Ubuntu onto my laptop. About a year ago I used wubi and installed Ubuntu and everything was working fine except occasionally Ubuntu would not boot and get stuck on some "PCI Port Error" (Something like that can't really remember now). Anyways, I got frustrated with the inconsistent start up of Ubuntu so I decided to uninstall wubi on my laptop.

After I uninstalled it, I tried to use wubi again and this time ubuntu would try to boot but it would freeze on a broken screen. Broken I mean, if I had Windows 7 running before it. Ubuntu would get stuck on this screen that seem to have screen captures or fragments of my Windows session. If I try to start wubi, without having the computer first boot into Windows it gets stuck on the same fragmented screen without the Windows screen captures. I've attached a picture to clear things up.
[image: Screen]

I've tried re-installing wubi a bunch of times and nothing has changed.

Comment: It looks like a maze!